# use promise for a method which uses ajax internally

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, promise

Ho do I use promise for a method that uses ajax internally ?. For example getStudents() is a method which has ajax call in its definition. I cannot modify this definition to implement promise right there due to certain policies. I can only apply promise to my own method that calls getStudents() as below :

`myMethod = function(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

```
    getStudents(); // this method internally make service calls using ajax and returns objStudData with Content or Error 

    if(objStudData.Content !== null && objStudData.Error == null){
        resolve('resolved');
    }
    else{
        reject('rejected');
    }
});
```

};
` 
So in the above example, getStudents() resolve runs event if objStudData is null, ie even before getStudents() has completed. What can be done to implement promise here. Thanks

Comment: Does `getStudents` returns promise?

Comment: `getStudents().then(res=>{ if (res.content==....}`

Comment: getStudents does not return promise.

Comment: can you share the code of getStudents.

Comment: how do you get `objStudData`?. can you send a callback function to `getStudents`?